# Prove that the group of invertible matrices acts transitively on Grassmannian space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, group-actions, grassmannian, general-linear-group

I have recently learnt about group actions and grassmannian space. So While searching further on the topic about general linear groups acting on different sets, I read something on wikipedia:

> $GL$($V$) acts transitively on grassmannian space

But I didn't find any prove regarding this statement.

My attempt was to define a map that takes the basis from grassmannian set to another basis within the set, but I couldn't really fill out the details and I am not sure how to construct a prove for this statement.

Comment: First show that you can go from the canonical basis to any chosen basis. Then show the opposite. Now put these together.

Comment: @Dan Rust, By canonical basis you mean standard basis $e_i$ ?

Comment: Yes, standard basis is another common term for it.

Comment: @Dan Rust Just to make sure i am getting this right, I will be taking a canonical basis for any subspace $U$  of dimension $k$,  {$e_1$,....,$e_k$} and if  i extend on these basis to form another basis for the vector space V , could i map the first basis to the second basis such that if forms an isomorphism ?

Comment: @Hannah_Zak No. Fix a basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $V$. Then $e_{i_1}\land e_{i_2}\land\dots\land e_{i_k}$ with $i_1<i_2<\dots< i_k$ form a basis for the $k$th grassmannian space.

Answer (score 3):

For each $T \in {\rm GL}(V)$, you can define $\widetilde{T}:{\rm Gr}_k(V) \to {\rm Gr}_k(V)$ by $\widetilde{T}(W) = T[W]$, where the latter denotes a direct image. This construction has a functorial behavior, that is:

- $\widetilde{T\circ S} = \widetilde{T}\circ \widetilde{S}$.
- $\widetilde{{\rm Id}_V} = {\rm Id}_{{\rm Gr}_k(V)}$.
- $\widetilde{T^{-1}} = \widetilde{T}^{-1}$.

This means we have an action ${\rm GL}(V) \circlearrowright {\rm Gr}_k(V)$ given by evaluation preceded with taking tilde. Given two $W,W'\in {\rm Gr}_k(V)$ take bases for $W$ and $W'$, complete them to bases for $V$, and define $T$ by mapping the basis for $W$ onto the basis for $W'$, and the remainder of one completed basis to the remainder of the other. Then $\widetilde{T}(W)=W'$ by construction.